# Why class or type on C# HTML.EditorFor doesn't work?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to add a class and a type on my Html.EditorFor, so I proceed like this :

```
Html.EditorFor(model_ => Model.MinDate, new { @class = "datepicker uk-input uk-form-small", type="date"})`
```

but still doesn't work.

This is the code in Chrome when I inspect :

```
<input class="textbox valid" data-val="False" data-val-date="The field MinDate must be a date." id="MinDate" name="MinDate" type="text" value="2018-01-19" aria-invalid="false">
```

And after research, I don't know why the class doesn't appaer. Can you explain me ? (sorry for my bad english)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this as:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model_ => Model.MinDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "datepicker uk-input uk-form-small" } })
```

Comment: I try but without succuss :/

Comment: Can you provide the relevant html once it has been rendred after you have tried this solution

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
I use "TextBoxFor" and not "EditorFor" and it works !

```
Html.EditorFor(model_ => Model.MinDate, new { @class = "datepicker uk-input uk-form-small", type="date"})`
```